# Php code inside string

Tags: php, string

I'm trying to chek if a server is online or offline but somthing is wrong where I chek the status ( $status =" function getStatus...) but I have no idea what's wrong. any idea?

```
<?php 
// This block grabs the whole list for viewing
$product_list = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM servers ORDER BY ID DESC");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
             $id = $row["id"];
             $name = $row["name"];
             $ip = $row["ip"];
             $port = $row["port"];
             $status =" function getStatus($ip,$port){
               $socket = @fsockopen($ip, $port, $errorNo, $errorStr, 3);
               if(!$socket) return "<FONT COLOR=red>offline</font>";
                 else return "<FONT COLOR=limegreen>online</font>";
            }
            //echo "$ip $port $errorNo $errorStr";
            echo getStatus("$ipi", "$porti");";

            $product_list .= "ID: $id - <strong>$name</strong> - <a href='edit_server.php?pid=$id'>edit</a> &bull; <a href='add_server.php?deleteid=$id'>delete</a>$status<br />
    }
} else {
    $product_list = "You don't have any servers!";
}



?>
```

Comment: Are you serious about that piece of code? Seems like quotation marks are all messed up. What is the assignment to `$status =` supposed to do? Please fix all these obvious errors before expecting serious answers and better tell us what exactly doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This getStatus function will not be executed.

You need to define it out of a string and then call it to get the info.

```
function getStatus($ip, $port)
{ 
    //Whatever you need to be run.
}
```

Then :

```
$status = getStatus("1.1.1.1", 80);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the lines

```
$status =" function getStatus($ip,$port){
           $socket = @fsockopen($ip, $port, $errorNo, $errorStr, 3);
           if(!$socket) return "<FONT COLOR=red>offline</font>";
             else return "<FONT COLOR=limegreen>online</font>";
```

is nothing more than a variable `$status` auto initialized with a string starting with `" function ...`. This obviously will not be interpreted as any code, so you might expect the function `getStatus` to not to be defined.

Unfortunately there are syntactical errors in the assignement as well, so that the php will never get compiled and you won't get that far. The interpreter will complain at `) return "<FONT` since there the string ends, a ; is expected but a < is follwing which is wrong syntax.

What you mean is:

```
         $port = $row["port"];
         function getStatus($ip,$port){
           $socket = @fsockopen($ip, $port, $errorNo, $errorStr, 3);
           if(!$socket) return "<FONT COLOR=red>offline</font>";
             else return "<FONT COLOR=limegreen>online</font>";
          }
          //echo "$ip $port $errorNo $errorStr";
          echo getStatus("$ipi", "$porti");";
```